# JSON/Table View/UI AlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I have an XCode project and in one of my View Controllers it parses JSON from a MySQL Database into a table view. The app is an app that helps you make a school schedule. What I want to do is when a user clicks on a cell in the table view, a UIAlertView pops up and it gives them the option to add the class from school into another tableview resulting in them starting to build their schedule. Here is some of my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"detailCell";
    // ClassDetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    ClassDetailCell *cell = (ClassDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClassDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.theLabel.text = nameString;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Course Name";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.theLabel.text = teacher;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Teacher";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.theLabel.text = location;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Bulding & Room";
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.theLabel.text = date;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Date";
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.theLabel.text = days;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Days";
            break;
        case 5:
            cell.theLabel.text = timeString;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Time";
            break;
        case 6:
            cell.theLabel.text = crn;
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"CRN";
            break;
        case 7:
            cell.theLabel.text = [addCLlass objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.detailLabel.text = @"Fall or Spring";
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"classdetailcell.png"]];

    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add This Class To Your Schedule?" message:@"Go Ahead!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"No Thanks!", nil];

    [alert show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {

    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"No Thanks!"])
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

}
```

I am able to get the UIAlertView to pop up in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. When a user clicks "No Thanks!" the VC is dismissed properly. Now when they click OK, I want the name of the course to be put in another table view. After its placed in the other table view, I want the user to be able to add classes, delete classes, and so on from the other table view. I also want the schedule to save to the device.

Suggestions would be great!

Comment: What does your data model look like right now? And where do `nameString`, `teacher`, etc get their values?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an ivar with the data you need, e.g. `selectedCourseName`. When a row is selected, update this variable. Then, when the alert is dismissed, you have the data to populate your next table view.